# Spring servlet mapping not working

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc

When I try to load `http://localhost:8080/people` I receive a 404 page not found error.

This is my servlet mapping iwthin web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/people/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is how I understand it works :

A url request to `http://localhost:8080/people` will be intercepted by the servlet "spring" and will invoke the class `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` Is this correct ?

Do I need some additional configuration in order for this class to be loaded correctly ?

Update :

Here is the controller :

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listPeople(Map<String, Object> map) {

        map.put("person", new Person());
        map.put("peopleList", personService.listPeople());

        return "people";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult result) {

        personService.addPerson(person);

        return "redirect:/people/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{personId}")
    public String deletePerson(@PathVariable("personId") Integer personId) {

        personService.removePerson(personId);

        return "redirect:/people/";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `people`? Is it the JSP page? If not then there is nothing to show and you will see a _blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `controller` backing to support your `GET` response?

Something like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/people")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/i_am_here", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String firstForm() {
        return "SHOW_ME_THE_JSP_PAGE";
    }
}
```

Based on above example, this will make your get URL request like -> /people/i_am_here

Method will be invoked and the response could be sent back in `JSP`.

[Checkout this example under Github](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke/blob/master/src/com/example/UserController.java)

https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke/blob/master/src/com/example/UserController.java

Comment: Okay so what is `people` string in the code? Does it refers to some web page? I have added a link to existing Controller. Please look at this example. If you have question then please let me know.

Comment: I don't know, this is a heroku app that I'm trying to configure. When add your code I get this message : "HTTP Status 404 - /spring-hibernate-template/WEB-INF/jsp/SHOW_ME_THE_JSP_PAGE.jsp" this makes sense to me as the .jsp is not configured yet. Does the code @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) act as the default get request mapping for a controller ?

Comment: Yes if you don`t specify anything then it act as a default. You could try adding mapping like `@RequestMapping(value = "/i_am_here", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. This will respond to URL request `/i_am_here` and the response would be `/i_am_here/SHOW_ME_THE_JSP_PAGE.jsp` or `/SHOW_ME_THE_JSP_PAGE.jsp` ( can't confirm without code). So in short if you put a debug point in the method then you can see how the URL mapping takes the effect. HTH

Comment: if I add a new '@RequestMapping' as you describe I dont think this can be invoked directly from the browser without adding a servlet mapping which matches the request mapping?

Comment: Updated my example. Please check it out